# How to Navigate from ChangeNotifier?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-provider

I am learning about [`provider` + `ChangeNotifier` for state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple), but I can't find any official guidance on how to implement a Navigation from a `ChangeNotifier`.

Let's say we improve the `provider_shopper` sample [here](https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/provider_shopper), so when the user clicks BUY, the `CartModel` does some buying logic and then Navigates to a Order Review page. How's this navigation should be implemented?

Do we provide a callback for the `CartModel`, so it will call it and trigger a Navigation on the UI?

Answer (score -2):

There might be a simpler and more elegant solution but I could only think of using one page and doing away with the Navigator:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appProvider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context);
    switch (appProvider.getCurrentPage()) {
      case 'home': return homePage(appProvider);break;
      case 'test': return testPage(appProvider,context);break;
    }  
    return homePage(appProvider);
  }
```

Each "page" is just a function that returns a Wigdet(a Scaffold):

```
Widget testPage(AppProvider appProvider,BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {return controlBackButton(appProvider,context);},
          child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test Page'),
        ),
```

Changing the page:

```
 void changePage(AppProvider appProvider,String page) {
    setState(() { 
      appProvider.setCurrentPage(page);
    });
  }
```

All pages except for the home page need to be wrapped in a WillPopScope widget in order to make the back button navigate to the home screen:

```
 Future<bool> controlBackButton(AppProvider appProvider) async{
    setState(() {
       appProvider.setCurrentPage('home');  
    });
    return false;
  }
```

It's not the best solution but a good start, I think.

Comment: I am pretty sure this solution isn't a good one, first you will lose the platform independent navigation animation, second you made all that code for a simple navigation that should be just one line of code, using what the framework already has, my suggestion of using a callback is way simpler.

Comment: It would be great if you can post an answer with code snippets. The challenge I had was that if you wrap the MaterialApp with a ChangeNotifierProvider, the provider will not have a Navigation object.

Comment: The Consumer will have a context. I can give an answer, but I was hoping to get one from the community.