# How to push a route from ChangeNotifier?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier

My question is quite simple: How do i initiate navigation from the ChangeNotifier?
I have a dashboard setup with a consumer and i want to change the route depending on the result of certain operations in the ChangeNotifier Model.

A similar question has been asked before but it has gone unanswered: [How to Navigate from ChangeNotifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330108/how-to-navigate-from-changenotifier)

Comment: Do you want navigate form changeNotififier  . example
class Aboutus with ChangeNotifier {}

Comment: Yes - thats exactly what i want. I don't know why i did not think of it...

Comment: please check answer if you have any doubt let me know

Answer (score 0):

Well it might seem obvious to all but me. You just have to pass the context into the ChangeNotifier and then you can `Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeName);`

I was searching for a way to make that happen from the widget tree in place. it did not occur to me to just do it from the model - and i am still not sure it is best practice - but it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
1. main.dart
 MaterialApp(
navigatorKey: NavigationService().navigatorKey,
)
```

2 create new class

```
class NavigationService {
 final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
  new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
 GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName) {
return navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(routeName);
}}
```

3. in Model class use this in any function

   ```
   NavigationService>().navigateTo(homePageRoute)  // your router name
   ```